# nginx rewrite rule causing 403 error

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, phalcon, http-status-code-403

I am using `Linux Mint 17.1 (Rebecca)`, with `Nginx`, and `Phalcon PHP`, and I am trying to get `rewrite rules` to work with it. The contents of php configuration files which is located in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

        location ~ $root/phalcon_tutorial {
                rewrite ^/$ /public/ break;
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1\.php break;

                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1 break;
                }
        }

        location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {

                #Credit to: www.slideshare.net/giorrgio/from-lamp-to-lnnp:
                #prevent cgi.fix_pathinfo=1 security hole
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                    return 404;
                }
                #EndCredit

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php5-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

and `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;

        location ~ $root/phalcon_tutorial {
                rewrite ^/$ /public/ break;
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1\.php break;

                if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1 break;
                }
        }

        location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404; 
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {

                #Credit to: www.slideshare.net/giorrgio/from-lamp-to-lnnp:
                #prevent cgi.fix_pathinfo=1 security hole
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                    return 404;
                }
                #EndCredit

        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php5-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

My nginx root is in the directory: `/var/www/html`

under that I am trying to do a `phalcon php` tutorial from this site: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html#checking-your-installation

they are using the folder `tutorial` for the root folder of this tutorial, but I am using the folder name `phalcon_tutorial` instead:

when I type in `localhost/phalcon_tutorial`, it should be rewriting that url to `localhost/phalcon_tutorial/public/index.php` but I am getting `403 Forbidden` error on `localhost/phalcon_tutorial` instead.

My directory under `/var/www/html/phalcon_tutorial/` looks like this:

```
phalcon_tutorial/
|
|_app/
| |
| |_controllers/
| | |
| | |_IndexController.php
| |
| |_models/
| |
| |_views/
|
|_public/
  |
  |_css/
  |
  |_img/
  |
  |_index.php
  |
  |_js/
```

The `index.php` file looks like:

```
<?php

try {

    //Register an autoloader
    $loader = new \Phalcon\Loader();
    $loader->registerDirs(array(
        '../app/controllers/',
        '../app/models/'
    ))->register();

    //Create a DI
    $di = new Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault();

    //Setup the view component
    $di->set('view', function(){
        $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View();
        $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');
        return $view;
    });

    //Setup a base URI so that all generated URIs include the "tutorial" folder
    $di->set('url', function(){
        $url = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
        $url->setBaseUri('/phalcon_tutorial/');
        return $url;
    });

    //Handle the request
    $application = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Application($di);

    echo $application->handle()->getContent();

} catch(\Phalcon\Exception $e) {
     echo "PhalconException: ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

and my `IndexController.php` file looks like:

```
<?php

class IndexController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "<h1>Hello!</h1>";
    }

}
```

I can't seem to find the solution. I was thinking it might be a permission problem. I changed all of the folders and files starting from `phalcon_tutorial` from being owned by `root` to being owned by `www-data` by doing `sudo chmod -R www-data phalcon_tutorial` from `/var/www/html`, and I changed all permissions of folders from `phalcon_tutorial` down to `755`, and I searched the internet and I thought maybe I had to disable `follow_symlinks`, so I went and edited `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and added `disable_symlinks off` under the `http block` - that file now looks like this:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

        disable_symlinks off;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

After doing all this I have restarted my `nginx server`, using the command `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart` - but like I said - when I go to `localhost/phalcon_tutorial` it is showing `403 Forbidden` error, but if I go to `localhost/phalcon_tutorial/public/` or `localhost/phalcon_tutorial/public/index.php` it is showing "Hello!"

How do I get this url rewriting properly using in `nginx` - without getting `403 error`? I am not very experienced with `url rewriting` or server config files in general, and I have been spending a lot of time searching the internet trying to figure this out and I am at a loss.

Comment: hello try to change `root  /var/www/html;`  to `root /var/www/html/phalcon_tutorial/public;`

Answer (score 2):

1. Entry of `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` should be symlinks to files in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`.

> Basically all your virtual host configs will be defined in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available directory`, to enable a config, you would create a symbolic link (or file shortcut) in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory, equally to disable a config, you would remove the symbolic link. Nginx will do the rest and search the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory for active virtual host configs.

(directive `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;`)

2. Have you tried understood problem with log files? I think, log files should contain info about wrong request and destination file.
3. I see that your config trying to include `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf` file, but you configured your site at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`(filename does not match given filemask ***.conf**)

Comment: I still couldn't solve this problem. Then I noticed I could use phalcon php's router instead - but I found that is even giving a 404 error for anything that is not set as the root directory. I've given up with getting phalcon php and nginx to work together - and decided to create my own very simple mvc framework for my projects and simply patch it up with pre written libraries as I need them.

Comment: Own framework should be cool:) But already exists better alternatives(for example symfony). You should understand who is broke your web-app. I would try carefully check rewrite directives(if exists), site-root, and analyze log-files to know what the problem.